# Creating new columns for values that are repeating more than once so that all the column values will be converted to a row through EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel, grouping, copying

Im modifying the question that I have already posted. My requirement is very simple.

## **DEFECT_ID    LOG_TIME    STATUS**

1001     08/22/2012 12:03:34    Open

1001    08/22/2012 12:03:35 Pending

1001    08/23/2012 02:13:46 Fixed

1001    08/23/2012 22:34:37 TestReady

1001    08/24/2012 12:34:43 Pending

1001    08/24/2012 19:13:39 Retest

1001    08/25/2012 22:13:40 Reopen

1001    08/26/2012 10:03:41 Retest

1001    08/27/2012 11:13:42 Closed

The above mentioned format is my 'Source' data. There will be 100s of such defects. As you can see, all the above log date and statuses belong to one single Defect_ID(1001).My actual work is I have to copy the above data into a new sheet in format that helps me to calculate the time difference between the statuses. To your attention, there are 'Eight' defect statuses: Open, Pending,Review,TestReady,Fixed,Retest,Reopen,Closed.And these defect statuses can occur more than one time in a single defect(As shown in above example, 'Pending' occurs twice. But openand closed will occur only once). Similarly there can be upto 6times a status can repeat for a Defect.So I need an output like this, where the log dates will be fitted into the corresponding statuses :

## *Defect_ID*  Open  Pending1 Pending2...Pending6 Fixed1...Fixed6 TestReady1..Testready6 Review1..Review6 Retest1..Retest6 REopen1..REopen6 Closed

Please let me know how to post pictures. if so I can show you how exactly I need the output through VBA. Please refer my other question: 'Copying values from one column that matches a ID to a new sheet by creating new columns for eeach values through EXCEL VBA', all I need in that is, I need new columns added up for every status that is repeating. so that all my values will be into one single row.

Comment: "Copying values from one column that matches a ID to a new sheet by creating new columns for eeach values through EXCEL VBA" - Please refer this question to get a better idea. All i need is when a 'Status' is repeating, then I need that value also populated into the row against the 'Defect_ID'. We can have 5-6 columns assigned for each status and populate them with the 'LOG' time when it appears. Am i clear???? Please help me... I am really struggling to work on this. AS daily I am manually copying this and doing.

Comment: Look at using COUNTIFS() to add a "count" column next to your status column. Add a second column concatenating status and count. Then create a pivot table using that joined column as column header, and id as row header.  If there are missing column headers (eg no pending6) then add a dummy id which has all the required status values you need as column headers.

Comment: Thanks Tim. But is there a possibility to make it through VBA. The prev. question has 'VBA' code that works for one instance of a 'Status'. But if you could make it for multiple instance, it will be great. The question im mentioning is, there in the 'First Comment'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some VBA that will do what you are looking for. (If I understand the requirements correctly).  It may be a bit verbose, but should be easy to maintain.  There is probably a more eloquent way of doing this.

```
Private Sub CreateOutputSheet()

   Dim iLoop, iStartRow, iEndRow As Integer

   Dim iPendingCount As Integer
   Dim iFixedCount   As Integer

   'Base Col Numbers
   Const colPending     As Integer = 3
   Const colColFixed    As Integer = 9
   '.....

   Dim sDefectIdCurrent    As String
   Dim sDefectIdPrevious   As String

   Dim iTargetRow As Integer
   Dim sCurrentStatus As String
   Dim dCurrentTime As Date

   sDefectIdPrevious = Sheets("Soure").Cells(intstartRow, 1)
   sDefectIdCurrent = Sheets("Soure").Cells(intstartRow, 1)

   For iLoop = iStartRow To iEndRow
      sDefectIdCurrent = Sheets("Soure").Cells(iLoop, 1)
      'Check the current problem
      If sDefectIdCurrent <> sDefectIdPrevious Then 'Reset the col counters
         iPendingCount = 0
         iFixedCount = 0
         '....
      End If

      sCurrentStatus = Sheets("Soure").Cells(iLoop, 3)
      dCurrentTime = Sheets("Soure").Cells(iLoop, 2)

      Select Case sCurrentStatus

         Case "Open"
            Sheets("Target").Cells(iTargetRow, 2) = dCurrentTime
         Case "Pending"
            iPendingCount = iPendingCount + 1
            Sheets("Target").Cells(colPending + iPendingCount, 1) = dCurrentTime
         Case "Fixed"
            iFixedCount = iFixedCount + 1
            Sheets("Target").Cells(colColFixed + iFixedCount, 1) = dCurrentTime
         '...
         Case "Closed"
            Sheets("Target").Cells(iTargetRow, colClosedNo) = dCurrentTime
      End Select

      sDefectIdCurrent = Sheets("Soure").Cells(intstartRow, 1)
   Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. But could you please let me know, in which columns should i be pasting the source values??? it shows me 'Out of range' error. :(

Comment: @user1563464 you probably need to change the sheet names from richard's code to match yours

Comment: @Enderland: I have already done that. I gave the sheet with source data as 'Source' and the other sheer as 'Target".

Comment: You will also have to set the iStartRow and iEndRow variables.  By default these values will  be 0.  At the start of the loop you will be looking for row 0 which does not exits.  You can manually set the row in code i.e  iStartRow = 3 'First row with Data.  Or create a function that works out where to start and end.

Comment: What line is causing the type mismatch?